# Android and JSch: SSH behind another SSH server

Tags: java, android, ssh, jsch

I'm trying to access a server behind another server within an Android app.  I can get into the first server and do things like edit files and upload/download.  The problem is getting into the second server via ssh using rsa keys.  The thing is, as a stand alone program compiled on my pc everything works fine, that is I could access the second server and do everything I could on the first.  When I try to implement it into my Android app, I can't get into the second server, only the first one.  I get a JSch error: Auth Fail when I try, even though I am using the same keys, and I'm sure I am doing things like I did before on my pc.  Is this a limitation on Android? Is there a work-around? I've used port 22 for both the first and second server, since it worked before, if that is relevant.

Comment: Try to [enable logging](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/jsch/index.php?title=Logging) and have a look what actually happens there. The "Auth fail" error message is quite non-clear.

Comment: I implemented it just like in the example except I save it to a log file rather than System.err and it reads: INFO: Disconnecting from _hostname_ port 22.

Comment: _hostname_ represents that second server that I can't get into, to be clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that this is a limitation on the server, for security purposes... I'll have to make a RESTful web application to communicate to this second server.

Comment: Thanks for coming back and providing an answer so we know where the problem was.